# What do the stats in Jet Set Radio Future do?

Tags: jet-set-radio-future

I've recently had the opportunity to play Jet Set Radio Future again, but I don't remember what any of these stats do.

What do the stats in Jet Set Radio Future do?

[image: Stats screen in JSRF]

Answer (score 2):

**Stamina** is health.

**G-stamina** is how much graffiti the character can take in Tagger's Tag mode.

**Spray** is how many spray cans they can carry.

**Graffiti** is how fast the character can spray each graffiti point on a medium, large, or extra large tag.

**Acceleration** is how fast they get to top speed while on the ground.

**Cornering** is just how they handle turns.

**Grind** is how easily they latch on to grindable surfaces.